# Does ambiguity in law go in favor of the defendant in a criminal case?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

Is it an out if the law a person is accused of breaking is ambiguous or in any way poorly written that an accused can be set free from it?

I cannot think that every law enacted are made equally. Sometimes laws can be rushed while some party has enough power to do so, without the necessary care and thought as to the precise practical implications of the law.

Surely, there must ways of dealing with poorly written laws when a person's future is at stake?

Comment: Alexander Hamilton said, "The rules of legal interpretation are rules of COMMONSENSE, adopted by the courts in the construction of the laws. The true test, therefore, of a just application of them is its conformity to the source from which they are derived." -Federalist No. 83
This was said on the subject of jury trials.

Comment: You shouldn’t confuse this with just not knowing the details, though. Also, “it was 100 pages” or some such won’t help you either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known as the *rule of lenity*.

> A common formulation of the rule of lenity is as follows: If a federal criminal statute is grievously ambiguous, then the statute should be interpreted in the criminal defendant's favor.

> Importantly, the rule of lenity does not apply when a law merely contains some ambiguity or is difficult to decipher. As this Court has often said, the rule of lenity applies only when “ ‘after seizing everything from which aid can be derived,’ ” the statute is still grievously ambiguous. The rule “comes into operation at the end of the process of construing what Congress has expressed, not at the beginning as an overriding consideration of being lenient to wrongdoers.”

Kavanaugh J., concurring, in *Wooden v. United States*, 595 U.S. ___ (2022), citing *Ocasio v. United States*, 578 U.S. 282, 295, n. 8 (2016), internal citations removed.

Answer (score 7):

If a law is not clear enough to let people know what is and what is not a violation, the law may be held to be void for "vagueness". But if it is clear that an act is a violation, even if some aspects of the law are unclear or ambiguous, that will not automatically be a defense for a person accused of breaking that law.

In some cases a court will add restrictions or clarifications to a law, and will treat it as if those had been included from the start. That may or may not create a defense for a particular accused. For example, a court may add that a certain action is only a crime if done "with intent to deceive". Other intent restrictions may also be added.

The outcome will depend on just what sort of ambiguity or careless drafting is involved, and how it affects the actual acts the accused did or is accused of doing.

Answer (score 6):

Poor writing of law is never a basis for overturning a conviction. Hard-core ambiguity might be, in which case the "rule of lenity" may choose between possible interpretations of a clause. See [US v. Universal C.I.T. Credit Corp.](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/344/218/), 344 U.S. 218

> when choice has to be made between two readings of what conduct
> Congress has made a crime, it is appropriate, before we choose the
> harsher alternative, to require that Congress should have spoken in
> language that is clear and definite. We should not derive criminal
> outlawry from some ambiguous implication.

re-cited in a chain of rulings up to [Dowling v. United States](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/473/207/), 473 U.S. 207 and beyond. However, there is the case of [US v. Yermian](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/468/63/), 468 U.S. 63, there the defendant made a false statement in a job application, and was convicted of violating [18 USC 1001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001) which said (wording at the time of the crime)

> whoever, *in any matter within the jurisdiction of any department or
> agency of the United States knowingly* and willfully falsifies,
> conceals, or covers up by any trick, scheme, or device a material fact
> or makes any fictitious, or fraudulent statements or representations,
> or makes or uses any false writing or document knowing the same to
> contain any false, fictitious, or fraudulent statement or entry

shall be punished.

Yermian knew that his statement (about convictions) was false, and contended that the prosecution had to prove both that he knew the falsity of the statement (the easy part) but also that the statement was made in a matter within the jurisdiction of the US. The job application was to a private company, who then submitted materials to the government to get a DoD security clearance, which he did not know.

The court decided that the "jurisdiction" clause was outside the scope of the adverb "knowingly. The court does not engage grammatical science to learn that the structure is ambiguous, they instead rebuff the lenity argument by appeal to other considerations. They conclude that

> Any natural reading of §1001 establishes that the terms "knowingly and
> willfully" modify only the making of "false, fictitious or fraudulent
> statements," and not the predicate circumstance that those statements
> be made in a matter within the jurisdiction of a federal agency

which is to say, they believe that the interpretation where "knowingly" refers to both "in the jurisdiction" is not natural. Technical ambiguity is not enough, one has to establish *likely* ambiguity, that is, it is *likely* that a speaker of English would arrive at both interpretations. There is a related interpretive doctrine known as the "last antecedent rule" which says that a modifier only holds of the *last* (nearest) possible thing being modified. The courts long ago devised this "first thing preceding" rule to resolve rampant ambiguity (even so, the rule is invoked mainly as low-level support for a conclusion that was reached by other means). In Yermian's case, "knowingly" might modify jurisdiction (which precedes) or "false" which follows. I don't disagree with their naturalness judgment – the important thing to notice here is that this narrows the scope of "ambiguity" from "possible ambiguity" to "probable ambiguity".

Another important part of the court's reasoning is based on legislative history, derived from reading earlier versions of the law (which, incidentally, has been re-worded since Yermian) – the "legislative intent" of the Congresses as a whole from 1918 up to the version applied against Yermian does seem to indicate a desire to prevent defrauding the government and there is no direct evidence that Congress intended to limit prosecution to just cases where a person also knew that the statement was "in a matter in the jurisdiction of the US". The court's conclusion is that all a person has to know is that they are making a false statement – it does not matter if they *know* that the statement is or has become "in a matter in federal jurisdiction".

The minority in this case (Rehnquist, Stevens, Brennan, O'Conner) find the language to be ambiguous, but that only shows that the particular conclusion about language is credible to reasonable legal minds. As the dissent puts it,

> Although "there is no errorless test for identifying or recognizing
> plain' or `unambiguous' language" in a statute, United States v.
> Turkette, supra, at 452 U. S. 580, the Court's reasoning here amounts
> to little more than simply pointing to the ambiguous phrases and
> proclaiming them clear. In my view, it is quite impossible to tell
> which phrases the terms "knowingly and willfully" modify, and the
> magic wand of ipse dixit does nothing to resolve that ambiguity.

[Liparota v. US](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/471/419/), 471 U.S. 419 presents a similar situation about ambiguous scope, regarding food stamp fraud, where the statute (7 USC 2024(b)(1)) identifies the criminal act as:

> Whoever knowingly uses, transfers, acquires, alters, or possesses
> coupons or authorization cards in any manner not authorized by this
> chapter or the regulations issued pursuant to this chapter

shall be punished. Again, there is ambiguity in the scope of "knowingly" – do you just have to know that you transferred the goods, or do you have to also know that the manner of transfer was not in compliance with the regulations? In this case, the court decided that the scope of "knowingly" must also extend to the authorization clause. In the holding, the court declares that "requiring mens rea in this case is in keeping with the established principle that ambiguity concerning the ambit of criminal statutes should be resolved in favor of lenity" (majority opinion written by Brennan, one of the dissenters in Yermian, which is cited in Liparota).

This is a topic on which books have been written. There is still no clear disposition of actually ambiguous laws.

Answer (score -2):

> Does ambiguity in law go in favor of the defendant in a criminal case?

It can, but the verdict must be formed according to Constitutional law in order to have a reasonable possibility of full access to leniency.

> Surely, there must ways of dealing with poorly written laws when a person's future is at stake?

There is a way of dealing with them:

Insist on a jury trial. The U.S. Constitution guarantees a jury trial in every criminal case.
That way you have access to the common sense, conscience, and reasonable sympathies of your peers, rather than being judged summarily by a member of the political establishment.
Judicial review of bad or poorly worded laws is vanishingly rare in the absence of jury trial, while jury nullification applies pressure on judges to review the law (Very few other things do).

Interestingly, all other answers so far ignore the Constitutionally specified modicum of arriving at a verdict in all criminal cases, which is jury trial. If you have access to a jury trial, you have access to common sense, which entails leniency whenever warranted. Relying on a court rule of lenity in the absence of a jury leads to a circular problem, in that you are left to rely on the mercy of the establishment charged with enforcing and adjudicating the same law that you question. What reasonable checks or balances exist in that environment? Too few.

Jury trial and jury nullification provide an incentive for judges to push back against ambiguous or overreaching laws: In the first place, it nullifies the judge's propensity to convict according to the law, however ill-constructed, and in the second place, defying the common sense of the masses will make a judge or prosecutor who insists on charging or convicting over bad laws look like an idiot or a tyrant, affecting their job security.

Comment: -1 "*The U.S. Constitution guarantees a jury trial in every criminal case.*" This is not correct when a crime is not punishable by imprisonment  or fines above a certain amount. "*Judicial review of bad or poorly worded laws is vanishingly rare in the absence of jury trial.*" This uncited statement is, I believe, incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately, jury instructions often include a judge's description of what the statute requires, as opposed to the actual statutory text.  If there's a difference between the instructions and statute which the judge insists is trifling, but which a defense believes may result in a jury that would acquit given the statute instead convicting given the illegitimate instructions, I don't know what options a defense would have to preserve the record so that an appeals court finding that the instructions were illegimate couldn't decide they weren't sufficiently erroneous to justify a new trial.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The US Constitution explicitly states "The trial of all crimes shall be by jury" (Article III, Section 2, Clause 3). Those who refuse a defendant's right to jury trial in any criminal case are therefore derelict.

Real world experience is sufficient to corroborate my claim. Judicial review is extremely rare nowadays relative to the number of cases where the law could (and should) be questioned. Most conspicuous in this trend is the complete absence of jury trials in most criminal cases.

Judges in bench trials tend to avoid questioning the law and instead focus on prosecution.

Comment: @supercat An application for a writ of habeas corpus should suffice to preserve any court records for appeal, including any questionable jury instructions, per 28 USC § 2245. The act alone of issuing an application for such a writ from a qualifying party under 28 USC § 2241 requires the judge to file a certificate setting forth the facts occurring at the trial, and renders them admissible as evidence. The writ need not be granted by the court in order to enjoin the deposition of these evidences and render them admissible; the hearing of a qualifying application alone is sufficient.

Comment: @pygosceles: Unfortunately, I've read many appeals-court decisions which said essentially "The jury instructions were erroneous, but since a reasonable jury given correct instructions could have reached the same verdict, there is insufficient basis for a retrial".  If e.g. a judge tells a jury they must convict if a defendant had 28 or more grams of X, when the statute actually says 28.3, and the defense had a bag containing 28.1 grams of X and another bag containing 2 grams of what the state claims was X but the defense claims was Y, a reasonable jury might find that the defendant had...

Comment: ...30.1 grams of X, which is greater than 28.3, but a jury might also find that the defendant had exactly 28.1 grams of X, which is less than 28.3.  In such a situation, would a defendant be able to have the jury go on record as to the exact amount of X they believed the defendant had, so that if the amount was less than 28.3 an appeals court couldn't claim that the 0.3 gram difference in the instructions didn't materially affect the outcome of the case?

Comment: @supercat I'm afraid I don't see the applicability of such fine-grained differences to the question at large, which has to do with ambiguity in the law itself.
In the case of a judge issuing instructions that are Constitutionally incorrect (for example, that a jury must convict according to what the law says), one liability instrument is the application mentioned, which would invalidate for example a conviction on grounds of belief or even proof that the defendant nominally violated any law.
Moreover: No fact tried by a jury shall be otherwise re-examined.

Comment: @pygosceles: If a jury is told to convict someone if they have a firearm with a barrel less than a certain length, and the statute says nothing about what portion of a barrel counts toward the length, and the BATF publishes some rules (front of closed breach face), and a judge gives instructions which would yield a shorter measurement (front of chambered cartridge casing), what "factual determinations" would be implied by a conviction?  Personally, I think that f the statute doesn't specify how to measure, the defendant should be allowed to use any reasonable means of measurement, but...

Comment: ...if a barrel is chambered for a case that's 1.5" long and extends 16.5" from the closed breach face, what factual finding would be implied if a jury who was instructed to measure from the case mouth said the barrel was less than 16"?

Comment: @supercat A jury cannot justifiably be instructed to convict anyone over any question of the law. Such instruction violates the separation of powers; verdicts in criminal cases belong to the jury alone. Juries may be informed of the law but are under no obligation to convict in agreement with it.
A jury's responsibility is to try fact as it relates to law, and to weigh equity irrespective of both. It may well be that concerns of equity outweigh both fact and law.

Comment: @supercat No factual determination is implied by a guilty verdict itself other than that the jury deems a charge applicable and reasonable to convict in that instance. This implies nothing at all about the validity of any individual fact used in evidence; it could be based on agreement with the spirit of the law. The jury may try facts individually and their determination about each, if given, must be entered on the court record and cannot be re-examined except under the conditions prescribed by the Constitution. In the case of a "not guilty" verdict, similarly no explanation is necessary.

Comment: @supercat Do you see how access to the common sense and conscience of a jury eliminates any quandary about fastidious fixation on fine-grained boundary conditions either defined or partially defined in the law? The law does not even have the final say in any matter of conviction. The first jury could declare that they find that the length of the barrel to have been less than 16", with or without an expounding of their rationale, but on appeal, the case must similarly be heard by a jury, and being a jury, they are empowered to re-examine that fact as I understand it, or by common law.

Comment: In no other way can a fact previously tried by a jury be re-examined. For example, a judge or prosecutor could not issue a contrary finding and have it be believed or even admissible. If the jury in the appellate court determines that the law itself or an application of it was fastidious, or without any explanation, they can overturn a prior conviction because conscience and common sense always trump the law by design. Subsequent juries are fully empowered to find the law fastidious, the facts immaterial or questionable, and to refuse to convict on the basis of conscience and common sense.

Comment: @DavidSiegel > "The U.S. Constitution guarantees a jury trial in every criminal case." This is not correct when a crime is not punishable by imprisonment or fines above a certain amount. 

Can you cite a Constitutional amendment that justifies this claim of exemption?

Comment: @pygosceles: //Do you see how access to the common sense and conscience of a jury eliminates any quandary about fastidious fixation// I see how it would do so if judges would recognize such behavior as part of a jury's duty, and cease their efforts to ensure that juries are ignorant of such things.

Comment: @supercat Yes. Of course this is also a matter of educating the public -- and is an excellent case in point as to why government control of education is a conflict of interests.